# Positioning Embedded Flash

Tags: css, flash, css-position, shockwave, embedded-flashplayer

I am triying to embed MixStream Flash Player to my website.

Scripts are as follows:

```
<script>
// MixStream Flash Player, http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/ 
var flashvars = {};flashvars.serverHost ="s8.streammonster.com:8241/;";flashvars.getStats = "1";flashvars.autoStart = "1";flashvars.textColour = "";flashvars.buttonColour = "";var params = {};params.bgcolor= "";params.wmode="transparent";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/v1.3.js"></script>
```

When I add codes above to my index page, html codes are generated as follows:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="mixstreamPlayerFlash" data="http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/flash/MixStreamPlayer.swf" width="335" height="50"><param name="bgcolor" value="000"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars" value="serverHost=s8.streammonster.com:8241/;&amp;getStats=1&amp;autoStart=0&amp;textColour=&amp;buttonColour=">
</object>
```

What I would like to do is to position this embedded flash. (as defining margin etc.) How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the id of the `object` tag to apply CSS to the element.  Something like:

```
#mixstreamPlayerFlash {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```